# Is there a "literary Olympus" in the current publishing landscape?

Tags: short-story

A biography of J. D. Salinger describes his eventually successful efforts to publish his short stories in The New Yorker, which is described as a literature Olympus of that time.

In today's publishing landscape, is there an equivalent magazine or venue which is generally acknowledged as the "ultimate" in quality and prestige?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Can you provide some context for your answer? Are you looking for a similar venue for your work?

Comment: I've edited to make this less of a hypothetical "what-if" and more on-topic. reader, I hope I'm in line with your intention for the question :) If you're new to Stack Exchange and how our site works, I invite you to [take our site tour](http://writers.stackexchange.com/tour) and get a feel for how things work here!

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, all, do you think this version is on-topic?

Comment: @Standback Yes, the edited version is better.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, no, I am only interested in this from the reader's perspective.

Answer (score 3):

In my perception, *The New Yorker* continues to be the pinnacle of literary prestige, at least for an American audience.